# How to get unique combination value from list of list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unique

I have a list of lists like

```
items = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]]
```

Need to extract only unique combination from the set, no repetition. For example [1,2] and [2,1] are same. In this case, we have to consider only one set.

Expected output: `[[1,2],[2,3]]`

How to achieve this using python ?

Comment: Please edit the code you have written to try solve this problem into your question as a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum code to get what you want is like this. If you must have the results as a list of lists, you’ll need a wrapper

```
set(frozenset(i) for i in items)
```

Or if it is not guaranteed that every item in the lists is unique in that list,

```
set(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in items)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
items = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]]
result = {tuple(sorted(c)) for c in items}
print(result)  # {(1, 2), (2, 3)}
```

Beware of how this affects the order of both the combinations in the result and the numbers in the combinations.

Comment: Not a bad solution, assuming that it's allowed for `results` to contain a value that isn't present in `items`. For example, if `items` is `[[2,1]]`, then `result` is `{(1,2)}`

Answer (score 1):

You could freeze all the inner lists to `frozenset`s and make a set of the outer list.

```
def deep_frozenset(container):
    """Freeze all lists into frozensets."""

    if isinstance(container, list):
        return frozenset(deep_frozenset(el) for el in container)
    else:
        return container

result = deep_frozenset(items)
assert result == frozenset({frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({1, 2})})
```

You can even write a `deep_thawset` to undo the operation.

```
def deep_thawset(container):
    """Thaw all frozensets back into lists."""

    is isinstance(container, frozenset):
        return [deep_thawset(el) for el in container]
    else:
        return container
```

you can even write a roundtripper.

```
def roundtrip(container):
    """Find all unique combinations.

    >>> roundtrip([[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]])
    [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
    """

    deep_thawset(deep_frozenset(container))
```

Comment: we can also define like this map(list, set(frozenset(i) for i in items)) // [[1, 2], [2, 3]]

Comment: @Sivachandran yep, my solution is overspec (list of list of lists are supported out of the box)

Comment: Though note that `map(...)` does not return a list, so it's actually `list(map(...))`

Comment: map(..) returns list .>>> res = map(list, set(frozenset(i) for i in items))
>>> type(res)
<type 'list'>

Comment: @Sivachandran ah, you're in Python2. You tagged your question as such -- my mistake! Well when you join us from the past, `map` won't return a list anymore ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set of frozensets for lookup:

```
items = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]]

result = []
lookup = set()

for subl in items:
    fs = frozenset(subl)
    if fs not in lookup:
        result.append(subl)
        lookup.add(fs)

print(result)
# [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]]
r=[list(i) for i in list({tuple(sorted(c)) for c in items})]
print(r) # [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

or

```
items = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]]    
u = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in list( sorted(c) for c in items))]    
print(u) # [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

or

```
items = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]]
d = list(list(x) for x in { (v,k) if k>=v else (k,v) for k, v in items  })
print(d) # [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: this prints [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1]] . [2,1] is again duplicate combination

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a set of frozensets:

```
items = set(frozenset(item) for item in [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]])
items
{frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({2, 3})}
```

Frozensets are immutable, which makes them hashable, which is necessary for being used as set elements.

Finally, to reach your desired output exactly, create lists from your sets:

```
list(list(item) for item in items)
[[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: list(list(item) for item in items) - this gives output as [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]]

Comment: @Sivachandran Not for above value of `items`.